# Как получить значение поля формы? javascript

Tags: javascript

В выпадающем списке выбираю дату:

```
<option value="1">31.05.2018 0:00:00</option>
```

В js пишу:

```
var date = document.getElementById('AttendDate');
```

В итоге получаю значение value равное 1. Как получить дату???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = document.querySelector('option:checked');
console.log(date.text);
```

```html
<select id="AttendDate">
  <option value="1">31.05.2018 0:00:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать атрибут "onChange" и передавать в него `this`.

```js
var getSelect = function(sel) {
  var date = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(date);
}
```

```html
<select id="AttendDate" onChange="getSelect(this)">
  <option selected>Выберите значение</option>
  <option value="1">31.05.2018 0:00:00</option>
  <option value="2">31.05.2018 10:00:00</option>
</select>
```